# how use jquery slidedown and slideup

Tags: jquery

i wanted ***.collpaseClass*** is ***SetHieght*** are slide..

- i wanted setHeight **.collpaseClass**  are slidedown and SlideUp When i am click **.more-optionClass**
- How use Jquery **Height Control** .

html

```
<div class="wrapmenu">
   <div class="tittle">Menu1</div>
   <div class="collapse"> xxxxxxxxxx </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapmenu .collapse{
   background-color: #fff;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 10px;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

jquery

```
$(".more-option").on('click',function(){

   //how use slideup and slide down

});
```

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2mnE5/)

Comment: be alittle more clear, u want the collapse to slide?

Comment: yes my friends . i wanted collapse is slide..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by following way:

```
$(".more-option").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).('.collapse').css('max-height')=='100px')
    {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').css('max-height', '300px');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').css('max-height', '100px');
    }
        //alert($('.collapse').css('max-height'));
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C8z5j/2/)

Comment: hey! my friends you answer is good but i wanted multiple class.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

or you can take a look on this with working example.

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/

or you want something else

**try this in w3schools the best and short cut**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({height:'250px'});
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden">
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wanted example fiddle.

Comment: wow for correct working example also i am getting down votes ha ha :D